# Devexpress batch update mvc grid data in client side

Tags: grid, devexpress

I am using devexpress mvc grid with batch edit mode. I want to check that if all rows dropdown from grid has been selected or not. So for that I want datascource of devexpress mvc grid in javasctipt/jquery. From that I can check and validate my grid. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do it in javascript, I will recommend you do it in batch updating method and if there validations fails then show validation.